# Use ksdensity with weight

Tags: matlab

How to apply "ksdensity" to a set of data with weights. For example, my data is 
[5 4 7 9], and the weight of each value is [3 2 1 2], which means there are 3 "5", 2 "4", 1 "7", and 2 "9", and I want to find ksdensity for them. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before applying ksdensity:

```
newData = repelem(OldData,weights)
```

This will duplicate each item according to its weight.

Comment: thank you very much, it's good to know.Can it be applied to non-integer weight?

Comment: No, I don't know the proper way to do floats. a quick fix is if you're dealing with small number of samples just multiply the weights by 10, 100 or 1000.